# Installing Docker in Google Cloud project

Tags: docker

How to install Docker in Google cloud Virtual machine ? I was not able to find Docker in Google cloud Tools - Kindly suggest

Comment: did you tried anything

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is "[Docker: Google Compute Engine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/gce/)"

Example:

```
$ gcloud auth login
$ docker-machine create --driver google --google-project PROJECT_ID vm01
$ docker-machine create --driver google \
  --google-project PROJECT_ID \
  --google-zone us-central1-a \
  --google-machine-type f1-micro \
  vm02
```

So all you need to do locally is [install `docker-machine`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/).